# Geometry nodes convert to instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

Can I convert the instances made with geometry nodes into real instances? If so, how? When I apply the modifier, it becomes one mesh instead of separate instances.

I am using Blender 2.93 LTS

Comment: Yes. When I apply the modifier, it becomes one mesh instead of separate instances.

Comment: you can use p>separate by loose parts after selecting all in edit mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of applying the modifier.
Select the object and search(F3) for "make instance real" and hit it.
This should create the instances.[image]